# Dimension of a vector subspace of $F_2^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be a vector subspace of $F_2^n$. Then, $|W| = 2^k$ for $k \leq n$. Is it always true that $\text{dim}(W) = k$? If it is, where can I find a proof?

Comment: It may be easier to go the other way. If $W$ has a basis consisting $k$ vectors, how many elements does it have? Try it this way, if you are stuck!

Answer (score 3):

Let $W$ be a vector subspace of $F_2^n$.
Let $k$ = dim($W$).
Let $w_1,\dots,w_k$ be a basis of $W$ over $F_2$.
Every element $x$ of $W$ can be uniquely written as $x = a_1w_1 + \cdots + a_kw_k$, where $a_i \in F_2$.
Hence as a vector space over $F_2$, $W$ is isomorphic to $F_2^k$.
Hence $|W| = 2^k$.